# How to use TF-IDF in PMID columns

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-science, tf-idf

Dataframe:

[image]

Code:

```
def word_count(sentence):
    return len(sentence.split())
    
df['word_count'] = df['PMID'].apply(word_count)
df.tail(10)
```

Comment: Consider adding some more details about your problem and about the things you tried already.

Comment: @Pradeep Pariyar does my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

v = TfidfVectorizer()
x = v.fit_transform(df['PMID'])
```